# Bluetooth Operation already in progress... Error

Tags: bluetooth, 18.10, python3, bluez

Sorry, I'm a beginner on Ubuntu 18.10, also my English is not very good, but I will try my best.

I bought a USB Bluetooth 4.0 dongle. When I plug the USB, everything is OK, the Bluetooth shows up. But if I try to search for my headphone or other tools, I get this error -
 [image: Bluetooth]

If someone can help, I would really appreciate and thanks for your answer.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/cUW0O5Y

Comment: If your adapter ID is 0a12:0001 and it is a clone (non-original), you are in troubles. Check this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth#CSR_Dongle_0a12:0001. I bought the same 3 days ago and I could get back. I will buy a non-clone one.